# 3d particle in a constant potential radial equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation

For the free particle in 3d, I follow [Robinett](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198530978)'s page 491 to find that the solutions to the radial equation are the spherical Bessel function $j_l(z)$ and $y_l(z)$ where $z=kr$ and $k=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}$.

If I allow for a constant potential $V=V_0$, and consider the $E<V$ case, then since the state are bound, I only use the regular Bessels $j_l(z)$.

I am struggling to figure out the other things that change in the solution. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Sphere_with_finite_%22square%22_potential) state the following:

$$ R(r) = A j_l (z) $$ with

$$ z= \sqrt{\frac{2m(E-V_0)}{\hbar^2}} r $$ and $A$ is some normalization.

1. Why is it $E$ MINUS $V_0$? if $E<V$ then this is negative and the function is imaginary from the $\sqrt{-1}$ no?
   Wiki is unclear on this, since they state

"We first consider bound states, i.e., states which display the particle mostly inside the box (confined states). Those have an energy E less than the potential outside the sphere, i.e., they have negative energy..."

but then directly below the $R(r)$ solution there is a contradiction with this:

"Note that for bound states, $ V_{0}<E<0$"

2. How is the normalization constant A solved for from the boundary conditions?

Comment: I think you should have a look at this: https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node227.html

Comment: @gert thank you for the reference! huh. it looks like I should be more concerned with the Hankel functions, since I an interested in the E < V case. Hmm more to think about. thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @gert i think the issue with using this constructure is that I would be assuming a barrier at some values of r. What if I am considering a constant potential everywhere? simply considering a state with E less than that V

Comment: It's not really a barrier, rather a boundary. W/o boundaries there can be no bound states (eigenstates). If $V=V_0$ EVERYWHERE you don't need to use spherical coordinates, you can use Cartesian $(x,y,z)$ coordinates. It's quite pointless IMO...